# A better way to say 'every arrow in his quiver'

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a better way to say 'every arrow in his quiver'?

Comment: In what context? If you are referring to literally all of the arrows that an archer is carrying in his quiver, I don't know a better phrase. If you are using it figuratively, it depends on the context. You might simply say "all", for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every argument he could think of* or, more simply, *everything he could think of*. Another idiom could be *every ace up his sleeve*.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

> Every tool at his disposal.

Comment: There is a slight difference, as the arrows in a quiver are all identical, but you might have a variety of different tools at your disposal.  Depending on the situation, this might make this a better fit, or a worse one.

Comment: @oldcat I interpret it  as "I used every arrow in my quiver but couldn't solve the problem" which would be identical to "I used every tool at my disposal but couldn't solve the problem".  I suppose clarification on context would shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idiom is quite good because it has a very clear use and meaning. Now, maybe if you find it too off-topic or would like to avoid it for any reason, I'd suggest little less sophisticated options such as:

He shot him with everything he's got.
He threw everything he's got at him.

Comment: Whether *at* is optional depends on intended meaning (i.e. to transfer vs. to target).  Note, *got* is not compatible with the idiom's meaning; here, it equals *obtained* when you probably mean *had*.

Comment: I think the expression is "with everything he's got" instead of "with everything he got", my bad. Regarding the meaning of "throw", I meant to target, like "I threw (at) you everything I've got" (in an attempt to hit you).

Comment: A couple of problems: 'He shot him' = once, so better 'He shot at him with everything he's got.' (Notice the verb tenses)

Comment: A couple of problems: 'He shot him' suggests once, so better 'He shot at him with everything he'd got.' (Notice the verb tenses). The second sentence has the same problem as with your question elsewhere. The 'at' is necessary, otherwise he'd be throwing things 'to' him. Although we'd normally put the prepositional phrase at the end, I think 'He threw at him everything he'd got' is OK, presumably because we have a relative clause modifying the direct object. (Please ignore previous comment)

Comment: @jwpat7 - 'got' is perfectly compatible. 'Have got' here is a perfectly acceptable variation of 'have', and has nothing to do with 'get' meaning obtain. See MWDEU - http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA498

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish - When I wrote my comment, the second sentence read:  "He threw (at) him everything he got."  Click "Edited 10 hours ago" to see editing history.  Re your extra comment, click "delete this comment", a small x just past the end of it.

Comment: I'm applying some corrections to the answer, according to a recent question on grammar and dative alterations.